# Wine: how to avoid creating system ("Windows") files?

Tags: wine

I want to use Wine programs, but I don't want `wine` to populate my `~/.wine/drive_c/windows` directory. The problem is that system files are just copied into every WINEPREFIX I use, and consume disk space.

Is there a way to tell `wine` to use symlinks and NOT copy files? Most files in `~/.wine/drive_c/windows` are immutable by design anyway.

Comment: Is creating those symbolic links manually an option?

Comment: @sebasth I guess not, since they are separate files (you _can_ have your own file among the `drive_c/Windows` directory).